# How to read $V^{\otimes n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $n$ an integer. How to read $V^{\otimes n}$? Could we read it as: $V$ to the power $n$? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: It is tensor outer product raised to $n$

Answer (score 2):

This is the $n$-fold tensor product of $V$:

$$
V\otimes\cdots\otimes V\qquad (n \text{ times}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You should read it as the $n$-th tensor power of $V$.
It is also written as $T^{n}(V)=V^{\otimes n}:=V \otimes ... \otimes V$ $n$ times. The tensor algebra, $T(V):= \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}T^{n}(V)$, where $V^{\otimes 0}:= K$, where $V$ is a vector space over $K$